# Can you create and publish an app on iOS without being an admin of your mac?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos, administrator

so I recently made an Android app and wanted to make it on iOS too now. Unfortunately, I do not have a mac myself but I can use one in my school. So my question is: can you make a whole app and publish it through a mac that you are not an admin on? Since I can only log into it and not as an administrator. xCode is already installed and works properly, plus, I have an iPad so I can test the app with it if necessary. (or use the emulator of course)

Thanks you!

tl;dr: can you create and publish an iOS app without being an admin of the mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To develop the app in the mac I don't think that there is a need for Admin rights. You can develop the app using xCode.To publish the app on the App Store you have to purchase Apple Account. Before publishing the app on the App Store you have to create the certificates and for using these certificate in your project you just need the keychain access. That's not a big deal.Admin rights are not so important for creating an app on the mac.

ALL THE BEST!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Developing the app would be fine. It’s once you are finished and you have to sign the app and upload to the App Store. That is where you might encounter some problems. I don’t believe you need admin rights in order to sign the application. It solely asks you to enter your password for your keychain , so you should be good to go.

Happy coding and good luck!

Comment: Code signing should be fine, unless it's an account shared by other people. If it's shared, you can't put your developer keys in the the user keychain (because anyone else using that account would have access to them, which is a big no-no). There are ways to work around this, but they're messy and require a fair bit of understanding of keychain management.